# Transform long form data to table with counts by events per common identifier

Tags: r, data-analysis, data-transform

I have a long form dataframe where I have a log of events occurring, each mapped to an ID.

```
df <- data.frame("id"=c("123","123","123","123","124","124","124","124","124"),
      "event"=c("run","walk","walk","walk","run","walk","walk","sprint","sprint"))
```

I would like to transform it to a dataframe with the number of times an event occurred (occurred once, occurred twice, etc) down the "y" axis, with the events across the "x" axis with the table being filled with the number of times the event occurred per ID.  In application, I wont know exactly how many rows I need ahead of time for the values in the times_occurred column.  I can use the row number for that; I just added in the code below for the sake of clarity.

```
results <- data.frame("times_occurred"=c(1:3),
                      "run"=c(2,0,0),
                      "walk"=c(0,1,1),
                      "sprint"=c(0,1,0))
```

To further clarify if needed, I am trying to get the occurrence data in the format I need for the 2nd chart here:
https://mode.com/blog/facebook-aha-moment-simpler-than-you-think/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this as start?

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  count(id, event) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=fct_reorder(event, n), y=n, fill=id)) +
  geom_col()+
  coord_flip()+
  xlab("Event")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  However, this results in an aggregation by id and event.  I am looking for an aggregation by count by id (down the y axis) broken out by the factor levels (run / walk / sprint) of the event (across the x axis).  Does that make sense?  Hard to articulate, take a look at the desired result dataframe in the original post.  Thanks!